# Reading RSS feed and displaying it in Django Template | feedparser

Tags: python, django, rss, django-templates, feedparser

Refer this blog: http://johnsmallman.wordpress.com/author/johnsmallman/feed/

I want to fetch the RSS feed for my application. The above blog is a wordpress blog.

I am using `feedparser`

```
import feedparser
feeds = feedparser.parse('http://johnsmallman.wordpress.com/author/johnsmallman/feed/')
```

Now `feeds['feed']['title']` Outputs `u"Johnsmallman's Blog \xbb John Smallman"`

My question is How exactly i present this in my app. Lets say this blog contains 100s of articles. So i want to loop over and fetch all data.

Isn't there any direct way of doing this? Any pre-defined library or method?

I have ofcouse googled but had hard time.

I am basically looking to render it to Django Template. So would really be looking something towards it.

Need guidance guys :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add `feeds` to your template context, you should be able to loop through it in your template:

```
<ul>
{% for entry in feeds.entries %}
    <li><a href="{{entry.link}}">{{entry.title}}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked in Django 2.0 with Python 3.6