# How to use Feedparser in Django Project

Tags: python, django, rss, feedparser

Could anyone direct me on how to include feedparser in my Django project? Essentially I'm building a news aggregator, so there will be 100's of rss feeds to parse through.

I understand the basic formatting and whatnot (running loops to display the feeds), but I'm not sure how to implement Feedparser.

Where exactly do I import it inside my Django project? And do I just hardcode the urls? Or is there a way to edit them from the admin page?

Comment: You should attempt to write some code first before asking.

Comment: Im sorry I'm about as big of a beginner as they come. All I have right now is a basic blog skeleton set up.

Comment: No problem! I would start by adding `feedparser` to your [requirements file](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html) or simply running `pip install feedparser` for now as you get going. Then check out [this post on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25411504/3538313). You could check out this [blog post](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/feedparser-and-django) and [this project](https://github.com/sveetch/django-feedparser) for some ideas on where to start